# =~ (equal-sign tilde) and m" ... " in .htaccess directive

Tags: apache, htaccess, httpd

I saw this bit of code on an old forum post:

```
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} =~ m"\.secure\.powweb\.com"
```

And I was just wondering what the `=~` and `m" ... "` meant. I've been searching online and in the Apache documentation for any mention of the *equal-sign tilde* operator, but I've found no mention of it. I know that some directives can take a tilde to use a regular expression, but I've never seen the `m" ... "` form used before.

What exactly is that `m" ... "` for? Where else would you see this form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is used for matching a regex in a string.

See [`man perlop`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/perlop):

> Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match.  Certain
>          operations search or modify the string $_ by default.  This operator
>          makes that kind of operation work on some other string.  The right
>          argument is a search pattern, substitution, or transliteration.  The
>          left argument is what is supposed to be searched, substituted, or
>          transliterated instead of the default $_.

and

> m/PATTERN/msixpogc
>          /PATTERN/msixpogc
>                  Searches a string for a pattern match, and in scalar context
>                  returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails.  If no string
>                  is specified via the "=~" or "!~" operator, the $_ string is
>                  searched.  (The string specified with "=~" need not be an
>                  lvalue--it may be the result of an expression evaluation, but
>                  remember the "=~" binds rather tightly.)  See also perlre.  See
>                  perllocale for discussion of additional considerations that
>                  apply when "use locale" is in effect.
>   ...
>   If "/" is the delimiter then the initial "m" is optional.  With
>                  the "m" you can use any pair of non-alphanumeric, non-
>                  whitespace characters as delimiters.